# Travelling through Turkey with Russian Passport

Tags: safety, russia, turkey

I'm not really into politics and a friend of mine advised me not to travel through Turkey due to political tensions. Now the price through Istanbul is twices cheaper than going through London.

Should I be worried about travelling through Turkey with a Russian Passport?

Comment: To the extent that it may matter, are you simply planning on catching a connecting flight through Istanbul or are you actually leaving the airport?

Answer (score 4):

I'm from Turkey and I don't think you should be worried about anything..

First of all, if anyone missed the situation, Russian and Turkish governments have some political crisis since [Russian Sukhoi Su-24 shoot down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Russian_Sukhoi_Su-24_shootdown) in 2015. And since 1 January 2016, [Russia's visa-free travel with Turkey was suspended](http://rbth.com/politics_and_society/2015/11/27/rusia-to-suspend-visa-free-travel-with-turkey-from-jan-1_545237).

I agreed with Zach. If your plan is transferring to another plane over Turkey to London, you should not be worried about anything. AFAIK, Turkish government doesn't applied any sanction for Russian passports or Russian people for this situation.

But if you plan is visiting the Turkey, [visa is *re*-required like before 12 May 2010](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/corporate/announcements/announcement/1-january-2016-visa-information-turkey-russia).

Comment: AFAIK, Turkish government did apply a sanction - they reinstated visa requirements for holders of Russian *service* passports.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy I do some research about this but I couldn't find any information about that _requiring visa for Russian passport even they transferred to another plane_. Is this sanction only for _service_ passport citizens for example? I don't know, this sounds little bit weird..

Comment: As far as I can understand, this only applies to officials entering Turkey. Just nitpicking on my part, irrelevant to the original question.